# Add k to the kTh node, starting from the end Recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion, linked-list, nodes

Given a linked list of integers and a number, k, add k to every kth node starting from the end. For example, if the list is [1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4] and k is 3, then the result is [1 -> 5 -> 3 -> 4]. The 2 was the third value from the end, we added three to get 5. No other nodes are modified.

For a longer example, consider the list:

[1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7]
If k=3, two nodes change:

[1 -> 5 -> 3 -> 4 -> 8 -> 6 -> 7]

Here's what I have so far, but I should probably be using some pointers and I can't figure out how to add k to the kth element once we reach it.

```
function solution(head, k) {

  if(head == null) return head;

  if(head.next) {
    for(let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    return solution(head.next, k)
  }
return head;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use recursion or do you want to use a loop? Don't mix them.

Comment: Oh crap. Yes, I was trying to use recursion for this problem.

Comment: Do you want to create a new list or do you want to mutate the argument list?

Comment: I need to modify the given list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not know the length or end node of the linked list, then you first need to find it by looping through it. From there, you can then loop through the linked list again and add `k` to the node's value if the length minus the node's index is divisible by `k`. Like this:

```
function solution(head, k) {
  // Get length of the list
  let len = 0;
  let ptr = head;
  while (ptr !== null) {
    ptr = ptr.next;
    len++;
  }

  // Loop through list and change nodes
  // with indices that satisfy condition
  ptr = head;
  let i = 0;
  while (ptr !== null) {
    if ((len-i) % k === 0) ptr.value += k;
    i++;
    ptr = ptr.next;
  }
  return head;
}
```

The crux of the code is this line:

```
if ((len-i) % k === 0) ptr.value += k;
```

`len-i` represents the `i`th index starting from the end, and the `% k` gets the remainder when divided by `k`, so if the remainder is zero (thus divisible), we want to add `k` to the node's value.

Note: My code assumes the value of the node is stored in the `.value` property. You may need to change this.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Could you clarify what is happening here `if ((len-i) % k === 0) ptr.value += k;` how do we know to do this? I'm rusty with my math skills lol.

Comment: @SharonKaufman Sure. `len-i` represents the `i`th index starting from the end, and the `% k` gets the remainder when divided by `k`, so if the remainder is zero (thus divisible), we want to add `k` to the node's value.

Comment: Ahhh I see it now, thanks for teaching me that!!

Comment: Is there a way to do this recursively?

Comment: @SharonKaufman Probably, but it would most likely be harder to understand than a loop version.

Comment: I couldn't get the code to work but I think it's my test cases that are wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can get the length of the linked list, then calculate which nodes to increment based on their indexes.

```js
function arrToLinkedList(arr) {
  let head = arr.length ? {value: arr[0]} : null, curr = head;
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) curr.next = {value: arr[i]}, curr = curr.next;
  return head;
}
function linkedListToArr(head) {
  const res = [];
  for (let curr = head; curr; curr = curr.next) res.push(curr.value);
  return res;
}
function solution(head, k) {
  let len = 0, curr = head;
  while (curr) ++len, curr = curr.next;
  curr = head;
  for (let i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    if ((len - i) % k === 0) curr.value += k;
    curr = curr.next;
  }
  return head;
}
console.log(linkedListToArr(solution(arrToLinkedList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]), 3)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to do

```
function length(head) {
  if (head == null) return 0;
  else return 1 + length(head.next);
}
function solution(head, k) {
  if (head == null) return null;
  else if (length(head) == k) return {value: head.value+k, next: head.next};
  else return {value: head.value, next: solution(head.next, k)};
}
```

However, this is really inefficient, since calling `length` on every list element gets us quadratic time complexity. The trick is to use a helper function that returns the length and the updated list together:

```
function helper(head, k) {
  if (head == null) return [0, null];
  const [length, rest] = helper(head.next, k);
  if (length == k) return [length+1, {value: head.value+k, next: rest}];
  else return [length+1, {value: head.value, next: rest}];
}
function solution(head, k) {
  return helper(head, k)[1];
}
```